# Getting two errors when trying to click Extend and Config tabs

Tags: 8

I'm getting the following errors:

> Drupal\Core\Extension\Exception\UnknownExtensionException: The profile does not exist or is not installed. in Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->getExtensionInfo() (line 346 of /app/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionList.php).
>   Drupal\Core\Extension\Exception\UnknownExtensionException: The module does not exist or is not installed. in Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->getExtensionInfo() (line 346 of /app/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionList.php).

These errors are not telling me what module is missing.  I have not installed any modules. The only thing that I've done is update core from 8.7 to 8.8.1
The only thing that I've done is update from Drupal 8.7 to 8.8.1.  Is there anything I can do to find what module is causing the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I found this Gist about [Fixing a Drupal 8 site with an empty install profile](https://gist.github.com/mparker17/1e44a65c0550bcde620c803beb537c74) related to your problem (which I also have). The guide solved the problems, but created another.

> Drupal\Core\Extension\Exception\UnknownExtensionException: The module minimal does not exist or is not installed. in Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->getExtensionInfo() (linea 346 di /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionList.php).

Looking for the second problem, I found this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3000677) and patch [#112](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-19/DrupalCoreExtensionList_0.patch) should solve all your problems without using the first guide I mentioned.

If instead you want to follow the guide, which I think is the best way to go, to solve the new problem do what comment [#110](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3000677#comment-13419761) says.
By adding the line `minimal: 1000` to the `core.extension.yml` file

Comment: Thanks @McAle, working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with Drush.

Please go to command line.

Change directory to document root.

Run this command:

`drush eval "\Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->reset()->getList();"`

This will fix the error.

PS: I am using `drush9`. So, please use correct version of `drush`.