# Module is required but can't uninstall because incompatible with core

Tags: updating, 9

I seem to be stuck with with a catch22, I updated from Drupal 8 to 9 and now I'm getting an error on many admin pages:

```
'The module t7_starbase does not exist or is not installed.'
```

drush pm-enable t7_starbase  results in:

```
  t7_starbase: The TEN7 Starbase module is required
```

it's not visible on backend pages either.

Comment: I think t7_starbase is a profile, not a module. https://github.com/ten7/starbase/tree/main/src/profiles/t7_starbase I am mentioning this because it may help to know that.

Comment: Yes I know , but Drupal is referring to it as a module in the errors.

Comment: Which version of Drupal 8 was it on? Is this question helpful? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/291212/getting-two-errors-when-trying-to-click-extend-and-config-tabs